Recurrence arising from Acceleration
In the original proof for acceleration (using plane-search), the following step (from (2.6) to (2.7)) starts with
$$
\sum_{I=1}^N \frac{v_i}{\sqrt{v_i - v_{i+1}}} \leq C(N)
$$
and concludes that $v_{N+1} \leq (C(N))^2/N^3$ (here, $C(N)$ stands in place of various problem-related constants and scales with $\sqrt{N}$, which I don't think should affect controlling the series sum).
To make this totally self-contained, we can say $v_i > v_{i+1}$ and all terms are nonnegative, the partial sum bound holds for all integers $k \geq 1$. That is, $\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{v_j}{\sqrt{v_j - v_{j+1}}} \leq C(k)$
Since the final result is relatively simple, I think I'm missing a technique in controlling such a recurrence. So far, I've tried using HM - GM - AM - QM, or just squaring both sides, but I'm not getting anything useful.
